How can I remotely login to my Pi running Bookworm
How can I remotely login to my Pi running Bookworm?
Previously this was possible using RealVNC.

Raspberry Pi Connect gives you access to Raspberry Pi 4/5 from anywhere (including your local network).
Your Raspberry Pi NEEDS to be running Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm.
Support for older devices extends this to ALL Pi models (including those running a 32-bit or Lite OS).
Only devices using the Wayland compositor have remote screen sharing (this means Pi5, Pi4, or Pi400) but ALL can access the remote shell.
Raspberry Pi Connect is the official Raspberry Pi Ltd. documentation but the following is a simplified version.
First install Connect with
sudo apt install rpi-connect or
sudo apt install rpi-connect-lite for only remote shell access or older Pi.
Next Create a Raspberry Pi ID
In a browser; navigate to id.raspberrypi.com enter an email address and password and Sign up to create your account. You will need to verify your email to continue.
Finally on each Raspberry Pi you must associate your Raspberry Pi with your Raspberry Pi ID.
On your Pi run rpi-connect signin which will generate an output like:-
Complete sign in by visiting https://connect.raspberrypi.com/verify/XXXX-XXXX
Visit the URL on any browser and sign into your Raspberry Pi ID to add your Raspberry Pi to your account.

Once you have completed the above you can connect to ANY of your Pi by logging into Raspberry Pi ID on any computer.
